# Python tkinter grid_forget()

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I want to make a label appear and disappear, but I am having a problem with `grid_forget()`.  This is part of the code:

```
def creabackuno():
    showinfo( "Wait..","I am creating the backup, please wait...")
    vsl=Label(gui,text="Working, please wait...",font=("arial",16)).grid(row=20,rowspan=1,column=0,columnspan=1,padx=10,sticky=N)
    try:
        copytree(path,r"backup\dirbackup1\.minecraft")
        showinfo( "OK!","Backup (1) created!")
        vsl.grid_forget()
    except OSError:
        showerror( "Nope!","There is already a backup to restore")
        vsl.grid_forget()
```

And this is the error of the console:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid_forget'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You currently have `vsl` equal to the return value of the `grid` method of `Label`.  Furthermore, this method always returns `None` (hence, the NoneType in your error).  Make your code like this:

```
vsl=Label(gui,text="Working, please wait...",font=("arial",16))
vsl.grid(row=20,rowspan=1,column=0,columnspan=1,padx=10,sticky=N)
```

Now `vsl` points to the label, not the return value of the `grid` method, which is `None`.

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you, this was driving me crazy.  I think too much jQuery in my past or something, I just didn't think to ask if chaining .grid() would return the item, and the Label/Button/etc was getting created and gridded without an error so I couldn't fathom why I couldn't destroy it.